# Installing GDAL on Windows with Python

Tags: python, gis, gdal, ogr

I'm attempting to install GDAL on my new work computer. I was attempting to use this process I found on another SO answer that I have used successfully at a previous job:

```
pip install wheel
pip install pipwin

pipwin install numpy
pipwin install pandas
pipwin install shapely
pipwin install gdal
pipwin install fiona
pipwin install pyproj
pipwin install six
pipwin install rtree
pipwin install geopandas
```

I get the error that "Package `six` not found" and the same for the geopandas install. Anyone out there have some insight into what could be happening here?

I am aware that I could use conda or OSgeo4W etc to install, I specifically do not want to do that.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

I did this in a virtual environment - I am not sure what would be causing this issue. I did try pipwin refresh which did not result in amelioration of the error.

Answer (score 0):

After extensive googling, I came across this resource [link](https://geoffboeing.com/2014/09/using-geopandas-windows/) which solved my problem for the time being. Will report back if this becomes unworkable in the future.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).